# Viewing NodeJS projects on other devices in the network

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I’m trying to view a CreateReactApp project from a different device. I tried setting the host to `0.0.0.0` by setting the “start” script to:

```
"start": "cross-env HOST=0.0.0.0 react-scripts start".
```

Though the console did log

```
Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: 0.0.0.0
If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your 
shell.
Learn more here: [URL BLOCKED BY GITHUB].
```

I could not access this project from another device on the same network using the computer’s IP.

At the same time I managed to access other projects (from a “tomcat” local server) on the same computer from the same device using the computer's IP. Any idea why this might be happening?
My environment: Windows10. I tried it on both ‘PowerShell’, and ‘Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (WSL)’, on more than one Create-React-App project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Defender Firewall was blocking the connection. It had a blocking rule for "NodeJs: Server Side JavaScript". To open the connection:

Settings => Update and Security => Windows Security => Firewall and network protection => Advanced Settings => Inbound rules => remove rules blocking node server.

Windows did not show a notification when blocking. It might be that at some point for some reason I authored it to block a connection to the nodeJS server.

Comment: I also discovered that Windows (10) was blocking Node by the firewall. I resolved it by accessing `Windows Defender Settings => Allow an app through the firewall`. Then in the list of apps find `Node.js Server-side JavaScript` (There may be a few). Ensure the checkbox for `Private` is ticked and then click 'OK'

Answer (score 2):

By default, Create React App serves the app in `localhost:3000`. So accessing `<ip address of machine serving the app>:3000` should work for devices in the same network.

Revert the change in start script in package.json and open the app in `<ip adress>:3000`

Comment: I tried it many times with no success. Perhaps it doesn't work well on Windows.